# Python 3.2 Tkinter - typed in directory to be source for file copying

Tags: python-3.x, path, tkinter, copy, move

I am trying to make a simple tool which will copy/move files with certain extension from one place to another. Everything is working out pretty much fine, but I am trying to make it possible to type in the directory where you want to copy from, and choose the directory where you want to copy to.

```
myGUI=Tk()
myGUI.geometry("400x200+100+200")
myGUI.title('Copy dat')

Source=StringVar()
Destination=StringVar()

MySource=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=Source).grid(row=9, column=2)
MyDestination=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=Destination).grid(row=10, column=2)


def copyy():
    source = os.listdir("Source")
    destination = "Destination"
    for files in source:
        if files.endswith(".jpg"):
            shutil.copy(files, destination)

button1=Button(myGUI, text="  Copy  ", command=copyy).grid(row=3, column=0)
```

But if I click on my button, the error message says that windows can't find directory named /Source or something like that. So I understand `source = os.listdir("Source")`is the problem. And I guess `destination = "Destination"` is also incorect. 
If I put the whole path in the code the copy button works well, but I want it to be possible to write the path in the window by the user of the tool. Please help.

edit: The whole code if needed:

```
import shutil
import os
from tkinter import *


myGUI=Tk()
myGUI.geometry("400x200+100+200")
myGUI.title('Copy dat')


Source=StringVar()
Destination=StringVar()

MySource=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=Source).grid(row=9, column=2)
MyDestination=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=Destination).grid(row=10, column=2)

def copyy():
        source = os.listdir('Source')
        destination = "Destination"
        for files in source:
            if files.endswith(".jpg"):
                shutil.copy(files, destination)

def movee():
        source = os.listdir("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/python testing/")
        destination = "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/python testing/destination"
        for files in source:
            if files.endswith(".jpg"):
                shutil.move(files, destination)

label1=Label(myGUI, text='Welcome to the copy utility', fg='Blue').grid(row=0,column=2)
label2=Label(myGUI, text='Ultimate JPG mover', fg='Black').grid(row=1,column=0)
label3=Label(myGUI, text='(Thing\'s actually pretty useless)',   fg='Black').grid(row=2,column=0)

button1=Button(myGUI, text="  Copy  ", command=copyy).grid(row=3, column=0)
button2=Button(myGUI, text="  Move  ", command=movee).grid(row=5, column=0)

myGUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `filedialog` for this purpose & also,browse buttons for that matter

Comment: If you want to continue in this way,you wanna use `binding` & `get()` to get the text entered in Entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some modifications:

- Used `class` (better coding technique)
- Used `filedialog`(for getting the path)
- Created `Browse` button
- Modified your code for `copyy` & `movee`.

Here,it is:

```
import shutil
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog

class MainClass():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.parent=master
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        self.Source=StringVar()
        self.Destination=StringVar()

        MySource=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=self.Source).grid(row=9, column=2)
        browse=Button(myGUI,text="Browse",command=lambda:self.Source.set(fdialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("JPEG File",'.jpg')]))).grid(row=9, column=3)
        MyDestination=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=self.Destination).grid(row=10, column=2)
        browse1=Button(myGUI,text="Browse",command=lambda:self.Destination.set(fdialog.askdirectory())).grid(row=10, column=3)

        label1=Label(myGUI, text='Welcome to the copy utility', fg='Blue').grid(row=0,column=2)
        label2=Label(myGUI, text='Ultimate JPG mover', fg='Black').grid(row=1,column=0)
        label3=Label(myGUI, text='(Thing\'s actually pretty useless)',   fg='Black').grid(row=2,column=0)

        button1=Button(myGUI, text="  Copy  ", command=self.copyy).grid(row=3, column=0)
        button2=Button(myGUI, text="  Move  ", command=self.movee).grid(row=5, column=0)


    def copyy(self):
        source_file=self.Source.get()
        if source_file.endswith(".jpg"):
            shutil.copy(source_file, self.Destination.get())

    def movee(self):
        source_file=self.Source.get()
        if source_file.endswith(".jpg"):
            shutil.move(source_file, self.Destination.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myGUI=Tk()
    app=MainClass(myGUI)
    myGUI.geometry("400x200+100+200")
    myGUI.title('Copy dat')
    myGUI.mainloop()
```

If you have any doubts,I would be happy to help :)

Comment: Very beautiful, thanks! Though Move button didn't work until I just copied the code for Copy button, and changed it's `shutil.copy` to `shutil.move` , don't know why. And now it copies instead of all .jpgs in the directory, just one specific which a bit changes the purpose of the tool. Other than that - you've helped me progress with this thing and showed me stuff that I have to do more research on :) So thanks a bunch and I'll keep learning nad trying out new things! Thanks again :)

Comment: Yeah i forgot to change that..sorry for that

Comment: If you want to get all files in  directory you want to look into [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)