# Why aren't my Text files not transferring with python GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to transfer any text files that have been modified or created in the last 24 hours from one file to another. So far the GUI allows the user to chose a source file and destination file, and when ran, no error happens but also no files get moved. Is there something I am not seeing?

```
import shutil
import os
import time
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog


class MainClass():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.parent=master
        self.gui()


    def gui(self):
        self.Source=StringVar()
        self.Destination=StringVar()

        MySource=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=self.Source).grid(row=9, column=2)
        browse1=Button(myGUI, text="Browse",command=lambda:self.Source.set(fdialog.askdirectory())).grid(row=9, column=3)
        MyDestination=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=self.Destination).grid(row=10, column=2)
        browse2=Button(myGUI,text="Browse",command=lambda:self.Destination.set(fdialog.askdirectory())).grid(row=10, column=3)


        buttonCopy=Button(myGUI, text="  Copy  ", command=self.copyy).grid(row=11, column=3)


    SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60
    now = time.time()
    before = now - SECONDS_IN_DAY

    def last_mod_time(fname):
        return os.path.getmtime(fname)

    def copyy(self):
        source_file=self.Source.get()
        if (source_file.endswith(".txt") and last_mod_time(src_fname) > before):
            shutil.copy(source_file, self.Destination.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myGUI=Tk()
    app=MainClass(myGUI)
    myGUI.geometry("400x200+100+200")
    myGUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just FYI, but `MySource`, `browse1`, `MyDestination`, `browse2`, and `buttonCopy` all point to `None`.

Comment: That's the idea, you chose which directories in the GUI. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: You have misunderstood. My point is that the names I mention don't point to sources, destinations, buttons, or anything of the sort. They are all `None`.

Comment: Your code will be _much_ easier to debug if you remove the use of `lambda` and have the button call a proper function. It's impossible to debug inside a lambda, and it provides absolutely no benefit.

Comment: I got part of this GUI design from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168209/python-3-2-tkinter-typed-in-directory-to-be-source-for-file-copying) , if you check the answer on this question you can see that his format is similar to mine. I tried his/hers code and it worked fine. Why would this be different for my case? @BryanOakley

Comment: You should be getting an error from the code as you haven't set `src_fname` - should it be `source_file`? What is the value of `source_file` when you enter `copyy()`? Indeed, since you use `askdirectory()`, you're only going to succeed it the directory is named `whatever.txt`...

Comment: Ok well I guess I will just have to go back to the drawing board. Thank you for your help. @BryanOakley

Comment: @NewDev: _"Why would this be different for my case? "_ - your's isn't different. I would have made the same remark there if I had seen it at the time it was written. The answer you copied from is not using best practices. While `lambda` is quite useful, you really should only use it when there is no better choice. It's not a good general purpose solution.